# Weird behavior updating store and re-rendering multi level slots

Tags: svelte, svelte-component, svelte-store

I'm new to svelte. I'm working in some generic components I intend to reuse in several pages, but with specific content that will be displayed by more specific child components. I have component A which is the parent, component B child of A and also generic, and component C child of B and it is supposed to be page specific. I'm using slots so I can choose a different component depending on the page. Each page will use a different store, so I pass the store down the hierarchy to the components, the store is an array of objects.

**Here is the app on svelte dev:**
https://svelte.dev/repl/e1bda22fb5fa4fc5bfbd38dff30d3f4b?version=3.58.0
*It is a simplification of my real code, but it reproduces the behavior.*

App.svelte

```
<script>
  import A from './A.svelte'
  import B from './B.svelte'
  import C from './C.svelte'    
  import {myStore} from './mystore.js'
    
  function debug(){
    console.log("store", $myStore)
  } 
</script>

<A dataStore={myStore} >
    <B slot="b" let:p data={p.data} dataStore={myStore} >
        <C slot="c" let:p data={p.d} fn={p.fns} ></C>
    </B>
</A>

<div>
    <button on:click={debug} >log store</button>    
</div>
```

A.svelte

```
<script>
    export let dataStore
</script>

<div>
    {#each $dataStore as d}
        <slot name="b" p={{data:d}} />
    {/each}
</div>

<style>
    div{
        border:1px solid blue;
        margin:3px
    }
</style>
```

B.svelte

```
<script>
    export let data
    export let dataStore

    function add(){
        let id = $dataStore.length + 1
        let name = numberToWord(id)
        $dataStore = [{name, id}, ...$dataStore]
    }
    
    function numberToWord(number){return new String(number)}
    
    const p = {d:{data}, fns:{add}}
</script>

<div>
    <h1>
        {data.id}/{$dataStore.length}
    </h1>

    <slot name="c" p={p} />
</div>

<style>
    div{
        border:1px solid black;
        margin:3px  
    }
</style>
```

C.svelte

```
<script>
    export let data 
    export let fn
</script>

<div>
    <input bind:value="{data.data.name}" />

    {#if data.data.id == 1 }
        <button on:click={fn.add}>Add Next</button>
    {/if}   
</div>

<style>
    div{
        border:1px solid red;
        margin:3px
    }
</style>
```

mystore.js

```
import {writable} from 'svelte/store';

export const myStore = writable([{name:'one',id:1},{name:'two',id:2}])
```

Everything works fine at first glance, the page render as expected.
[image]

But then when I click add next and add more items to the store this happens
[image]

The first item is displayed correctly and it is correctly binded to the object on the store, but all the following items are displaying the last object on the store, which is an array, and all of them are binded to it. if I add 10 more items all of them will be the same as the last object on the store.

It is like some sort of closure but I have no clue why this is happening. If I click log store, it is correct, so the store is being updated, but it is rendering incorrectly, anybody can explain what is going on?

Comment: The question should contain all relevant code. If it is a lot, try to simplify it as much as possible first.

Comment: This might be due to the `#each` block not having a key https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks